# Random variable describing number of shooting stars in terms of number of clear days in a month

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, random-variable, bernoulli-distribution

If the number of clear days in June each year is modelled as a (truncated) Poisson random variable, and the chance of seeing a shooting star observed on a clear day is modelled as a Bernoulli random variable, what sort of random variable describes the total number of days shooting stars are observed in June?

So I think:

1. The random variable $X \sim \operatorname{Pois}(\lambda)$ models number of clear days in June, for a smallish $\lambda$ to avoid having the right truncate the distriburtion.
2. The random variable $Y \sim \operatorname{Bern}(p)$ models the success probability of observing a shooting star on a clear day.

I am interested in the random variable $Z$ with support on the non-negative integers $k$ describing the number of days shooting stars are observed, then:

$$P(Z = k) = \sum_{i \geq 0} P(X = i) P(Y' = k | X = i)$$

where $Y'$ has the Binomial distribution with $i$ trials and trial success probability $p$. Is there any simplification of this probability density function and does it have any special properties?

Comment: Your assumptions are about a 'model' ... but you then ask what sort of random variable 'describes' reality (the number of observed shooting stars). Who knows? Is the model a good model or not? Is the number of shooting stars observed a random process, or just fitted nicely by some distribution? And if the latter, does it 'describe' the empirical reality you refer to anyway? And how would you know?

Comment: I do not know whether the model for the number of shooting stars in June is good or not, nor am I interested in this. I am primarily interested in some algebra of two random variables and any interesting properties of the resulting random variable.

Comment: But that is not what your question asks. Perhaps different wording would do the trick for you ... How would your question and model change, for instance, if you were considering the number of cloudy days in July?

Comment: I don't understand, wouldn't I just change June -> July? The months don't really make a difference either?

Comment: Sorry, I just realised that some of the confusion may have been bad wording on my part. I am interested in the random variable describing the number of days shooting stars are observed.